# How to work with ParametricNDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

Update 3: I got it. A small dumb mistake... It has to be `Evaluate[xP[y]'[0] /. s10]` like this. Oh well...

Update 2: So if do this `Evaluate[xP'[y][0] /. s10]` regardless of what you set as y the output is always 0 even though the starting velocity in the direction of x is 1000. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? `Evaluate[xP[y][t] /. s10]` works as it should.

Update: I managed to include variable intial conditions with `ParametricNDSolve` as user21 suggested. But now the function `bVP` doesn't work anymore. Now for `bVP[y,0]` the output is always 1 regardless of y. Also after the swing-by the smaller I set y (the greater the distance), the greater is the output. What needs to be changed to calculate the speed of the probe? I also changed the old code below with the `ParametricNDSolve` one.

Currently I'm trying to make a simulation of a swing by maneuvre, in which I send a probe around the Moon. For now there is only the probe and the Moon but eventually it will be expanded. I'm doing this using differential equations. The goal of this is to find out how the distance and the starting velocity affects the gain of velocity.

Now I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the initial conditions variable so that I can plot the ratio of inital and final velocity dependent on distance and starting velocity.

This is the working code so far:

```
grav12x[r1x_, r1y_, m1_, r2x_, r2y_, m2_] := 
G m1 m2 (r2x - r1x)/((r2x - r1x)^2 + (r2y - r1y)^2)^(3/2)
grav12y[r1x_, r1y_, m1_, r2x_, r2y_, m2_] := 
G m1 m2 (r2y - r1y)/((r2x - r1x)^2 + (r2y - r1y)^2)^(3/2)
tmax = 24*60*60*30;
G = 6.67*10^-11;
mMoon = 7.349*10^22;
mProbe = 3000;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{
xM''[t] ==
 (grav12x[xM[t], yM[t], mMoon, xP[t], yP[t], mProbe])/mMoon,
yM''[t] ==
 (grav12y[xM[t], yM[t], mMoon, xP[t], yP[t], mProbe])/mMoon,
xP''[t] ==
 (grav12x[xP[t], yP[t], mProbe, xM[t], yM[t], mMoon])/mProbe,
yP''[t] ==
 (grav12y[xP[t], yP[t], mProbe, xM[t], yM[t], mMoon])/mProbe,
xM[0] == 0,
yM[0] == 0,
xP[0] == -100000000,
yP[0] == y,
xM'[0] == -1000,
yM'[0] == 0,
xP'[0] == 1000,
yP'[0] == 0
}, {xM, yM, xP, yP}, {t, 0, tmax},{y}]
```

Now I want for example yP[0] to be variable so that I can plot this

```
bVP[y_,t_] := 
 Norm[Evaluate[{xP'[y][t], yP[y][t]} /. s]]
```

which describes the magnitude of the velocity.

I know this is wrong but I'm looking for something like this:

```
vVerhältnis[k_] := Replace[y, y -> k] && bVP[60*60*24*8]/bVP[0]
```

I'd like to plot that as a function of, in this case, the vertical distance.

I'll be very thankful if anyone could help me out :)

Comment: Could you please put the code for the constants in your post. For example what are `tmax`, `G`. What you are looking for is `ParametricNDSolve` and then you can make a sensitivity analysis.

Comment: @user21 I added the constants to the code. I'll try it with ParametricNDSolve.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is much simpler using vector notation in `NDSolve[ ]`;

```
tmax   = 5 10^5;
G      = 6.67*10^-11;
mMoon  = 7.349*10^22;
mProbe = 3000;

grav12[r1_, m1_, r2_, m2_] := G m1 m2 (r2 - r1)/((r2 - r1).(r2 - r1))^(3/2)

s = ParametricNDSolve[
  {M''[t] == (grav12[M[t], mMoon, P[t], mProbe])/mMoon, 
   P''[t] == (grav12[P[t], mProbe, M[t], mMoon])/mProbe,
   M[0]   == {0, 0},      P[0]  == {-10^9, y},
   M'[0]  == {-1000, 0},  P'[0] == {1000, 0}},
  {M, P}, {t, 0, tmax}, {y}]

ParametricPlot[(P /. s)[100000][t], {t, 0, 495000}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]